# case statement logic

Tags: t-sql, case

Let's make this easy.

I have a table.

```
visitID   studentname      dob       roll.no     value    displIndex     propID
200019      rob         05/18/1937     101      smoking       2             83
200019      rob         05/18/1937     101                    2             91
200019      rob         05/18/1937     101      alcohol       1             83
200019      rob         05/18/1937     101                    1             91
200020      henry       08/20/1987     102      smoking       2             83
200020      henry       08/20/1987     102                    2             91
200021      king        09/21/1982     103      alcohol       1             83
200021      king        09/21/1982     103                    1             91
```

I have a table of a similar kind.

Now what I am trying to do is if there is no display index of 1 for that particular `visitID` of that student, then in the case statement return a value of  `'779'`.

```
select visitID,studentname
       ,dob
       ,roll.no
       ,value
       ,dispIndex
       ,propID
       ,case 
             WHEN (PATINDEX('%smoking%',value) >0 OR
                  (PATINDEX('%sometimes smoking%',value) > 0) THEN
                        '777'
              WHEN (PATINDEX(%not smoking%,value) >0 OR
                   (PATINDEX(%do not smoke%,value) >0_  THEN
                          '778'
             WHEN (ISNULL(CAST(value as varchar(max)),'')='') THEN
                          '779'
              ELSE
                          '779'
             END VALUE
```

Here King doesn't have a record under smoking. So I want it to go into the 779 bucket. How can I perform that?

Comment: If habit is free text, you have [data modification anomalies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Free_the_database_of_modification_anomalies). And not sure what you want either. I can't see how fields relate between tables for starters

Comment: Also some sample output is a good.  Also also, **it does not show a lot of care in your own efforts when you misspell keywords in your sample query!**

Comment: what is `s.value`?, and what represent the numbers you are obtaining with the `CASE` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're doing a cast here (based on your sample data), so change this:

```
WHEN (ISNULL(CAST(value as varchar(max)),'')='') THEN '779'
```

To this:

```
WHEN ISNULL(value,'') = '' THEN '779'
```

Also -- realize that the way you're doing your wildcards, all of your 'not smoking' values are going to be '777' because they match the first pattern `(PATINDEX('%smoking%',value)` (i.e., the 2nd pattern won't even be checked).

**EDIT**
answers to your questions in the comment:

---

1) How will it pull the record of king-->smoking-->displayIndex 2?
**Answer**: There is no record in your sample set for King with a displayindex of 2.  You can't pull a record that isn't there.

2) I want to check for ... alcohol records.
**Answer**: You already solved that problem for the smokers & non-smokers.  Just do the same kind of thing for alchohol.  For example: `WHEN PATINDEX('%alchohol%',value) > 0 THEN '779'`

3) I would like to put the king student under 779
**Answer**: He is.  The way a `CASE` statement works, if none of the `WHEN` conditions evaluate to `true` (i.e., `...WHEN PATINDEX('%smoking%',value) > 0`) then the ELSE statement is used.  Since none of the WHEN statements will evaluate to `true` for King, he will be under `779`.

Comment: How will it pull the record of king-->smoking-->displayIndex 2? When there is no record present for king under smoking?  I want to check for all the students available for the smoking records and as well as alcohol records. Now king has reocorded only alcohol not smoking. I would like to put the king student under 779.

Comment: I'm having a little difficult understanding your question, but see my amended answer.  If you still think King is not under 779, then please state why you think so -- *He's not there because...X*.

Comment: I need to pull all the student records with alcohol and smoking. irrespective they have it or not. In the above case as you can see that king does not have a smoking recorded. I want the king's roll no, or the visitID go to the 779 bucket.