# CASE statement, assign multiple value in THEN section

Tags: mysql, database, controls, case

This has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122431/case-statement-logic) but I'm not sure it was clearly answered. How do you assign multiple values in the THEN portion of a CASE statement. According to the MySQL manual "[Each statement_list consists of one or more statements;](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-statement.html)", so I'm wondering how this is done.

I have a THEN in my CASE statement and would like to assign a value to two variables. So something like THEN @var1 := 'something', @var2 := 'something else' ESLE 'something more' END.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to assign variables inside of the case itself, unless MySql is that different from TSQL, but here is how you can accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT @va1 = CASE WHEN Some_condition THEN 'something' ELSE 'something else' END,
       @va1 = CASE WHEN Some_condition THEN 'something' ELSE 'something else' END
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Pulling a bit from the link you posted from the docs:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procase()
BEGIN
    DECLARE var1 INT;
    DECLARE var2 INT;

    SET var1 = 1;
    SET var2 = 20;

    CASE var1
        WHEN 1000 THEN SELECT var1;
        WHEN 3000 THEN SELECT var1;
        ELSE
        BEGIN
        -- multiple statements; statement list right below
        -- performing multiple variable value setting
            SET var1 = var1 + 200;
            SET var2 = var2 + 200;
            SELECT var1, var2;
        END;
    END CASE;
END
```

Encapsulate multiple statements within a `BEGIN...END`.. See if this works